# How to use Access' OpenRecordset to get a record using its numeric key field?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, vba

I have a problem in Access 2010 VBA trying to read a record from table to write it into TextBoxes.

My table is "Products" and its ProductID field is numeric. I used this method before, but it just works for **text fields**, not for **numeric** fields (ProductID is autonumber).

```
Private Sub GetProduct(ID As TextBox, Name As TextBox, Price As TextBox)
    If ID <> "" Then
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Productos", dbOpenDynaset)

        'PROBLEM IS HERE
        rs.FindFirst "ProductID=" & "'" & ID & "'"

        If rs.NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "The producto doesn't exist."
            Price = ""
            Name = ""
        Else
            Name = rs!ProductName
            Price = rs!Price
        End If

        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, help me. This is for a Final Proyect and I don't know other, but this method. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to see you figured it out.
The problem is that ProductID is numeric and your code specifically tests for a text field

```
    rs.FindFirst "ProductID=" & "'" & ID & "'"
```

putting a single quote each side of the parameter makes Access parse the parameter as a string.

If ID is 123, this will read

```
    rs.FindFirst "ProductID='123'"
```

and you get a type error

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution!

```
    rs.FindFirst "ProductoID=" & ID
```